# Ruby on Rails: error whenever running any rails command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have tried several times to install rails. Using RVM, then compiling the source myself, then using RVM again... every time the install looks like its worked fine but when i then try and run

```
rails -v
```

.. or any rails command, I get:

```
internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- /home/user/config/boot (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

ruby seems to work fine, as does gem.
I have searched all over an cannot find information on what the issue could be.
I am running Ubuntu 11.04 and have installed the latest release of the rails gem (not the RC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you running this command from? It looks like you are running it from your home directory where you've accidentally run `rails new .` and then deleted `config/boot.rb` but *not* deleted `script/rails`. Then, when you run `rails -v` that command is detecting there is a `script/rails` folder there and attempting to load the stack as if your home directory were a Rails application.

Remove `script/rails` from your home directory and try again.